# Cannot update nuget package (PCL)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm getting this error when using maps in Android:

```
System.MissingMethodEsception: Method
'Xamarin.Forms.maps.Android.MapRenderer.OnCameraChange' not found.
```

And I've read that you can update the nugetpackage to fix the issue. However, I cannot install it due to this:

```
Could not install package 'TK.CustomMap 2.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

The updates of packages installs just find in iOS and Android but not for PCL. I've tried to remove all the packages and then tried to add TK.Customs nuget package but this same issue.

Also tried to install it on a fresh project and that installed just fine. Just cant get it to install on my old project.

Here is the whole error message when trying to update package:

```
 Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'TK.CustomMap.2.0.1' with respect to project 'Vernamo', targeting '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/tk.custommap/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/tk.custommap/index.json 175ms
Total number of results gathered : 29
Gathering dependency information took 232 ms
Summary of time taken to gather dependencies per source :
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -   204.03 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'TK.CustomMap.2.0.1' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'TK.CustomMap.2.0.1'
Resolved actions to install package 'TK.CustomMap.2.0.1'
Found package 'TK.CustomMap 2.0.1' in '/Users/holger/Downloads/Vernamo/packages'.
For adding package 'TK.CustomMap.2.0.1' to project 'Vernamo' that targets 'portable45-net45+win8+wp8'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'TK.CustomMap.2.0.1' does not exist in project 'Vernamo'
Executing nuget actions took 52 ms
Could not install package 'TK.CustomMap 2.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Forms Package Erorr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964193/xamarin-forms-package-erorr)

Answer (score 1):

The pre-release version (at least *pre2*) of *TK.CustomMap* supported all platforms (see [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TK.CustomMap/2.0.0-pre2)), anyway, as of *pre3* (see [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TK.CustomMap/2.0.0-pre3)), obviously the support for all platforms was dropped in favor of .NET Standard (1.1 in this case).

The profile you are using in your PCL does not seem to be compatible with .NET Standard 1.1, hence NuGet fails to add the reference. You may try to switch to another profile (.NET 4.5.1 for example), but I don't know if that would help. Another option would be to migrate your projects to .NET Standard. It's kind of a stupid, repetetive task, but it's possible.

Comment: If I make the project .Net Standard. It would probably affect other packages and code right? @Paul Kertscher

Comment: @petterandersson Yeah, theoretically it is possible that it would affect code, but with .NET Standard 2.0, you should be able to use more of .NET Framework than with PCL. Anyway, of course you would have to test thoroughly.

Comment: @petterandersson AFAIK, if you are using .NET Standard 2.0 you should be able to use all 4.5 and 4.5.1 PCLs, hence this should not be an issue. I've just ported a mid-sized code-base to .NET Standard and it still works like a charm.